# How to use a Vertex AI Managed Dataset for hyperparameter tuning op

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to create a Vertex AI Pipeline to perform a hyperparameter tuning job **that reads the data from a Vertex AI Dataset** to have the metadata functionality track the relationship between dataset, model and endpoint (once I deploy the best model).

I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/master/components/google-cloud/google_cloud_pipeline_components/experimental/hyperparameter_tuning_job/hp_tuning_job_sample.ipynb) that reads directly the data from tensorflow_datasets, but I don't see any way to pass a Vertex AI dataset to the [hyperparameter tuning job op](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-0.2.1/google_cloud_pipeline_components.experimental.hyperparameter_tuning_job.html?highlight=HyperparameterTuningJobRunOp#google_cloud_pipeline_components.experimental.hyperparameter_tuning_job.HyperparameterTuningJobRunOp).

Do anyone know how to access a Vertex AI Dataset in a Hyperparameter tuning job?

Thank you.

Comment: did you solve the issue? I have the same problem

Comment: No, I finally gave up on this

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `hypertune` to the notebook so that it can write the different hyperparameters and their performances at the interface:

```
import hypertune

hp_metric = f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average='weighted')    
    
hpt = hypertune.HyperTune()
    hpt.report_hyperparameter_tuning_metric(hyperparameter_metric_tag='accuracy',metric_value=hp_metric,global_step=100)
```

And also add args to tune the model:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # Input Arguments
    
    parser.add_argument(
        '--max_depth',
        help = 'RF model parameter- depth',
        type = int,
        default = 100
    )
    
    parser.add_argument(
        '--max_features',
        help = 'RF model parameter- Features',
        type = int,
        default = 34
    )
    
    parser.add_argument(
        '--max_leaf_nodes',
        help = 'RF max_leaf_nodes',
        type = int,
        default = 8
    )
    
    parser.add_argument(
        '--min_samples_leaf',
        help = 'RF min_samples_leaf',
        type = int,
        default = 1
    )
```

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. My problem is regarding how to use a Vertex AI Dataset while performing a hyperparameter tuning job in a Vertex AI Pipeline